# Bitcoin hash calculation

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, hash, sha256, genesis-block

Best regards

I have been doing a lot of research about bitcoin and blockchain. A lot of informacion across the Internet can be found where many people explains the basics of bitcoin an it´s underlaying technology, but I have a question that I can´t quite find the answer and beg for this community help

If one searchs in Google Almighty one can track down bitcoin to the first block issued which is told  to have the hash:

000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f

on Blockchain.info the transaction info made is available:

https://blockchain.info/block-index/14849

And I even found a blog where the original block data containing the now famous ¨The Times 03/Jan/2009 Chancellor on brink of the second bailout for banks¨ is given

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block

But, to which data I have to apply SHA256 in order to get the given hash?

Many people say that is to block header copossed by Version - Previous block hash - Merkle Root - Timestamp - Difficulty Target - Nonce in the block structure, but another question arises for me:

When a pool is mining, does it receives the block info and its hash? From who receives that data?

Hope you can help me, any readings/books/videos/resources you can recommend will be appreciated or threads where this question has already been answered!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Blockchain.info is not the official website of Blockchain. it is just blockchain viewer

Answer (score 1):

> But, to which data I have to apply SHA256 in order to get the given hash?

You need to apply recursive hashing to all the transactions in the block(in a correct order) to create a merkel tree, and then hash the final hash from the merkel tree with infos that you mentioned

> When a pool is mining, does it receives the block info and its hash? From who receives that data?

When mining, the miners get the hash of the previous block. Transactions are read from the Mempool. And try to create a valid block(that satisfy the difficulty target) by doing trillions of trillions of hashing (POW)

I would recommend [Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) by A.Antonopoulos. It's my reference to everything in the Bitcoin space

PS: answering by email is definitely against stackexchange policy